# Issue with Routing and ng-view

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, routes, ng-view

I have a problem with my single Page Application. When I start my Project with the keyuser.html as first site(home page) the Table from the connected Database is shown with the Data. When I use the normal home.html as entry Point for my Program, I can click the Hyperlink to my keyuser.html file, the controller does the necessary routing and I am on my keyuser.html site. But here is just the update Button, but not my Table with my Data.

+++++++++ keyuser.html ++++++

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="update()">Update</button>

<div id="flexGrid"></div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
var cv = new wijmo.collections.CollectionView();
var flexGrid = new wijmo.grid.FlexGrid('#flexGrid');

flexGrid.itemsSource = cv;
// Get Data
wijmo.httpRequest("/api/Colors", {
    success: function (xhr) {
        cv.sourceCollection = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    }
});
</script>
```

++++++++++++ control.js ++++++++++++++

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

 app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
    .when("/keyuser", {
    templateUrl: "keyuser.html"
 });
```

++++++++++++ home.html ++++++++++++++

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.latest/controls/wijmo.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.latest/controls/wijmo.grid.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body> 
 <div ng-app="myApp">
   <a href="#!keyuser">Stammdaten</a>
   <div ng-view></div>    
 </div>
```

Comment: I think you missed to give angular routing file reference please add and check it

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong here.

First of when loading HTML templates with routing the entire template gets loaded into the ng-view element. Which means that in your case the doctype tag, html tag, body tag and all the other tags are loading twice which might break your page.

Secondly when using AngularJS do not write your javascript in script tags, instead start using controllers, directives, componentens and services.

And last, make sure to include the correct AngularJS scripts like angular.js and angular-route.js

In general i highly recommend just going through the basics of AngularJS before proceeding because i feel like you are missing those.